# DateTimeFormatter not compatible with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;


public class Test001 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date dt = new Date();
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz").withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");

        System.out.println(formatter.format(localDateTime));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(dt));
    }

}
```

### Output

```
2016-04-19 11:25:34.917 ET
2016-04-19 11:25:34.637 EDT
```

The timezone of my laptop is *"America/New York"* (i.e. Eastern Time US/Canada).

I wonder how to get "EDT" instead of "ET" by using `DateTimeFormatter`.
I wonder also in general: why is the `DateTimeFormatter` not compatible with `SimpleDataFormat` in terms of parse/format patterns (as this example shows they are not compatible).

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` class is pretty much a legacy class at this point since Java 8. ["**Version note**: This Date and Time section uses the date and time APIs in the `java.util` package. The `java.time` APIs, available in the JDK 8 release, provides a comprehensive date and time model that offers significant improvements over the `java.util` classes. The `java.time` APIs are described in the Date Time trail. The Legacy Date-Time Code page might be of particular interest."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl OK, well, but there's also quite a lot of legacy code around. And we may want to preserve the old formats.

Comment: Basically, it's not compatible because you should longer be using it. :p

Comment: Technically, "America/New York" is not EDT, it is ET. It happens to also be EDT at the moment but it will be EST in winter. So they are clearly not equivalent.

Comment: @assylias No offense but I don't care what it is technically. I care that I have tons of Java 6,7 code producing EST/EDT and now I don't know how to produce the same with Java 8's java.time. I thought that java.time would be compatible with the old way (as far as format and parse is concerned at least).

Comment: @peter.petrov I understand - what I'm saying is that EDT (or EST) are not really time zones - that's why they are not available. So you will probably have to either stick to Dates or change the timezone manually (checking if the dst is on or not for example). Somebody else may have a solution though...

Comment: I see... yes, I know they are not time zones technically. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to write up an answer, but the following link explains how to deal with the new DateTimeFormatter and legacy code. [Date/Time Formatting/Parsing, Java 8 Style](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.de/2014/09/datetime-formattingparsing-java-8-style.html). Hope you can get along with that piece of information.

Answer (score 10):

The format you are seeing "ET" is known as the "Generic non-location" format in [Unicode Locale Data Markup Language (LDML)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-43/tr35-dates.html#Time_Zone_Format_Terminology). The format you want, "EDT", is known as the "Specific non-location" format.

The relevant source code in [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) checks to see if the date-time object can supply [`ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#INSTANT_SECONDS). If it can, then the "specific non-location" format is used, if not then the "generic non-location" format is used.

Since you are formatting a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), which does not support access to `ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS`, you are getting the "generic non-location" format. To get the output you want, use [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) or [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) instead. (The instant is needed to determine whether it is summer or winter time.)

Note that [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) do differ and it is not correct to assume the patterns are identical. The decision was taken to resynchronize `DateTimeFormatter` with the LDML specification, which will have benefits in the future.

This answer provides a solution and an explanation, however I must note that the JDK code is being overly harsh here. Since you are supplying both a `LocalDateTime` and a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html), the code should be able to do better, and determine `ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS` on the fly and thus use the "specific non-location" format. Thus, I think there is an edge case [JDK issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154567) here.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a closer look based on your answer.

Comment: If you carefully study the [LDML-specification](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Using_Time_Zone_Names) then you will find that the pattern symbol "z" is intended to stand for the specific non-location format, not for the generic variant. LDML instead wants the symbol "v" for generic non-location format. Obviously, there is no library including Java-8 which supports "v". If Java-8 is supposed to closely follow LDML then "z" should NOT support generic variant. Consequently, the combination of local types like `LocalDateTime` with pattern symbol "z" should better be rejected.

Comment: Sure, 'z' is indeed only the "specific" format. but LDML is written based on the concept of only working with `java.util.Date`/`Instant`/`ZonedDateTime` type objects. In JSR-310, we have more types that LDML did not consider, such as `LocalDateTime`. JSR-310 also does not claim to match LDML exactly - it is used as a guide. As such, generalizing the spec to use the "generic" form when there is insufficient data is entirely appropriate.

Comment: I totally share your analysis about the LDML-Intention to focus on instant-like types but it seems your conclusion is not the only possible way. Even in context of local types (like `LocalDateTime`) it would be IMHO clearer for users if they just understand "z" as "specific-non-location-format" only. Why do you not support the symbol "v" (= resynchronizing with LDML) instead of mixing up the behaviour of "z" (generalizing aka changing LMDL-behaviour)? At least documentation of your reasoning would be fine. By the way, I haven't yet seen any API-doc about "generic non-location format" yet.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't be operating on a `LocalDateTime`. The (almost)equivalent of `Date` is `Instant`. You'll want to format an `Instant` as if it was in your timezone. So

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz").withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
Instant now = Instant.now();
System.out.println(formatter.format(now));
```

which prints

```
2016-04-19 12:07:57.684 EDT
```

Alternatively, you can use a `ZonedDateTime` without setting a `ZoneId` for your `DateTimeFormatter`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");

ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")))
System.out.println(formatter.format(now));
```

which also prints

```
2016-04-19 12:11:01.667 EDT
```

I don't have the documentation for why this all works, but the gist is that these temporals (the date object you're trying to format) have offsets, which have zone rules, which can be daylight saving time or not. The formatter uses that in its printing.

A `LocalDateTime` does not have an offset or timezone. Your formatter overrides it but with an offset that is not daylight saving time.

Comment: You made a very good point with saying that `java.util.Date` primarily maps to `java.time.Instant`. So if OP complains about incompatibility between both format engines, he should at least care about using the right equivalent type for `java.util.Date`. Otherwise this incompatibility statement is not quite fair (in this context - leaving aside the fact that there are incompatibilities in other details - for example different pattern symbols).

Answer (score -2):

Most straight forward approach (and probably also causing some issues with summer/winter time is as follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date dt = new Date();
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        String dateFormat;
        if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET) != 0) {
            dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS 'EDT'";
        } else {
            dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS 'EST'";
        }
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat).withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

        System.out.println(formatter.format(localDateTime));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(dt));
    }
```

Comment: So when the DST happens, the poor developer is going to be called in the middle of the night and change the code of the fly?

Comment: Refined answer so that it takes DST into account.

Comment: @Tunaki No, `Calendar.getInstance()` uses the default time zone taking DST into account. So this answer is undoubtedly very awkward and limited (not straight forward for me), but not completely wrong (although only working in New York zone and English locale). Let's say, it is insufficient.